# Is there something special using min-height as percentage?

Tags: css

I'm trying to force my **content** div to fill the whole **wrapper** div.

The **wrapper** is set up to force my footer to the bottom of the window, or page.  Which it does just fine.

If I use:
min-height: 500px (or 40em); the **content** div stretches as requested.

However, if I use:
min-height: 100% (or any other %); nothing happens to the **content** div.

This makes no sense to me.  What am I missing?

Per the request (excluding borders and colors and stuff):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {  
  min-height: 100%;  
  width: 80%;  
  margin: 0 auto -4em;  
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;   // nothing happens, change to em or px something happens.
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 4em;
}
#push {
  height: 4em;
}

<body>
  <div wrapper>
    <div header>
      <div menu></div>
    </div>
    <div sidebar></div>
    <div content></div>
    <div push></div>
  </div>
  <div footer></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "line-height: 100%" on your content div. Although... if there is an explicit height set on your wrapper div, you should be able to use 100% on one of the various height measurements to force it to expand.

Post some quick example markup that shows your wrapper and your content.